# Jboss - mapping IP instead of localhost - works from within eclipse But not from run.bat without options

Tags: eclipse, jboss, ip, localhost

I start the JBOSS server from within eclipse and it is able to bind to the computer name [ ip address] , but when i try to start it using run.bat , it just binds to 127.0.0.1 .

From run.bat :

```
*INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase : http://127.0.0.1:8083/*
```

From within Eclispe :

```
*INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://myIP:8083/*
```

So is it something that Eclipse uses different files , whereas run.bat uses separate ones .

---

**My Analysis :**

---

When the server starts , the run.jar is called , inside which there is a Main.class

> C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\jboss-5.0.1.GA\bin\run.jar

and in this  : *org.jboss.Main* and this sets the property to 127.0.0.1 :

```
this.props.setProperty("jboss.bind.address", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("jboss.bind.address", "127.0.0.1");
```

Then it checks if any option i.e. -b or something else has been specified and if so then uses it .

So i understand , why JBOSS without any options connects to 127.0.0.1 and with an option connects to the specified IP .

But what i still cannot understand is why does Eclipse connect to my ip . I am not specifying any options , or maybe i am but i don't know . So if anyone can point me to that Or maybe does it have its own implementation of JBOSS , or different files set ??

Answer (score 12):

The answer being that you can set it in eclipse . I guess it got set for my server Or by default it is already set .

[image]

And since it is set to -b 0.0.0.0 .. So it works .

Wel it took me close to 2 hours to figure this out . I just hope someone stumbles it on quicker .

There are a lot of other threads , but they just don't specify this step .

Hope it helps .

Comment: I have started the jboss with -b 0.0.0.0 option and I could see my machine name bound with the http://myIP:8083/* .  When I invoke from browser with my ipaddress like http://myip:8080/ not works , I am getting the error like "The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time". I have deployed esb service which will listen 8080 port .

Comment: Due to the Proxy setting,  it is not working in my browser . It is works after disabling the proxy configuration in browser.

Answer (score 2):

After adding server to Eclipse IDE from:

1. Preference->Server->Runtime Environments
2. Add Jboss Server

Then select your required project and from the context menu select 
Run As -> Run On Server
Then select your added Jboss server and then replace the:
Server's host name field value from localhost to your PC IP address.
[image]

Then click Finish.
Hope this will work
Thanks.